# MIPS Problem in printing the array and get the third element multiply to 4

Tags: arrays, loops, assembly, mips

I'm new to MIPS and I'm stuck in the printing array and the function also kinda mess up
This is my code, it works for the get input I guess but after that, they display the array and have error.
This is the question:

1. Prompts the user to input an integer number between 1 and 10 using the console
2. Write a function to initialize an array of 5 elements with the value entered by the user. This function must include the following

A loop

A branch

3. Write a function to multiply the third element of the array initialized above by the number 4.
4. Write a function to print all the elements of the array to the console. The third element must be 4 times the other elements. This function must include the following

A loop

A branch

Your code must have three separate functions (in addition to the main section) and function calls

Function to initialize the array

Function to multiply the third element of the array by the user input number

Function to print the arrays to screen.

```
.data
    array: .space 20
    prompt: .asciiz "Input 5 integers\n"
    .align 3
.text
main:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt
    syscall
    
loop:
    beq $t0, 20, exit
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    sw $v0, array($t0)
    add $t0, $t0, 4 #increase index
    j loop
exit: 
    jr $ra
print_loop:
    la $t1, array # get array address
    li $t2, 0 # set loop counter
    beq $t2, 5, exit_print_loop
    lw $a0, ($t1) # print value at the array pointer
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    addi $t2, $t2, 1 # advance loop counter
    addi $t1, $t1, 4 # advance array pointer
    j print_loop # repeat the loop
exit_print_loop:
    li $v0, 10
```

Comment: _"it works for the get input I guess"_. You don't have to guess. Use the debugging features of a MIPS simulator like SPIM or MARS to see exactly what happens. _"and have error"_. **What** error? Please be more specific.

Comment: If you're supposed to have 3 functions, you should probably have 3 calls, and 3 returns, but there's no calling in this code, and there's only one return.

Comment: Thank you, I think I have a problem with the array pointer, I reset it but it does not, so I just to another register and it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code that I made and it works perfectly for my test. Thank you!

```
.data
    array: .space 20 #create an array for 5 integer
    prompt1: .asciiz "Input 5 integers from 1 to 10 \n"
    prompt2: .asciiz "\nThe array is: \n"
    prompt3: .asciiz "Third element times 4 is: "
    newLine: .asciiz "\n"
    .align 3
.text
main:
    #prompt the user input
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt1
    syscall
    jal loop 
    #Calculate and print out the result
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt3
    syscall
    jal cal
    #Print out the array
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt2
    syscall 
    addi $t1, $zero, 0 #clear t1
    jal display
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
loop:
    beq $t0, 20, exit
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    sw $v0, array($t0)
    add $t0, $t0, 4 #increase index
    j loop
exit: 
    jr $ra
cal: 
    la $s5, array
    lw $t5, 8($s5)
    mul $t3, $t5, 4
    li $v0, 1 
    move $a0, $t3
    syscall
    jr $ra

display:
    beq $t1, 20, exit_display
    lw $t6, array($t1)
    addi $t1, $t1, 4
    #print current number
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t6
    syscall
    #print the new line
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, newLine
    syscall
    j display
exit_display:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```